# How can to make iisreset remotely?

Tags: iis, remote

how can I make iisreset remotely to a server that exist in another domain .. i have the admin credentials for this server ..

Answer (score 0):

```
iisreset <machine_name>
```

if you are on the same network.  If not, create a vpn so you can access the network remotely.